# Map opening in Indian Ocean on QGIS Web Client?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-web-client

After installing web part of qgis i created a project with layers. All layers are working, but i always need to scroll the map to reach these layers. How can I open the map exactly there i want? I tried to set epsg in file GlobalOptions.js, created file in the path site/libs/proj4js/defs/ with the correct arguments, added epsg parameter to openlayers.js, but still it opened indian ocean. Also in the project under the crs properties i added right crs.

Comment: When you say that the layers are all working , do you mean that they show in the correct location?

Comment: Yes, they are..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you properly define the CRS in QGIS -web-client and you are sure that is the only CRS that you are using (if there are 2 CRS's in use on the same project you might get pink tileS), you will have to set the CRS in your project also. After you've done all that the client should open your project the same way it opens in QGIS desktop. So if you go to atlantic ocean and save your project there, then run it in the client, it should start up in the same location.

But sometimes you want QGIS to zoom to something specific on start, which we can use the URL for. So first you will need to add some code to the Customizations.js which can be found in client/site/js folder.

You should add the following code "block"s to the function customAfterMapInit():

```
    //first we split the url
    var getParams = document.URL.toLowerCase().split("?");
    //coordinateTextField.setRawValue(getParams.length.toString());
    var inX = -1;
    var inY = -1;
    for (i = 0; i < getParams.length; i++){
        var compared = getParams[i].substring(0,2);
        if (compared.localeCompare("x=") == 0){
            //we found the X parameter, remember i
            inX = i;    
        }
        else if (compared.localeCompare("y=") == 0){
            inY = i;
            //we found Y parameter remember i
        }
    }
```

Now we have to check the values of parameters and zoom to them.

```
    if (inX == -1 && inY== -1){
        //this happens when there is no parameter given
        //change the zoom level to something you want,
        geoExtMap.map.zoomToScale(60000);

        //you can also set to zoom to some coordinate
        //but you will need to define the predefinedCenter first.
        //I used the definition in the else and please change the
        //function parameters from 1234.5678 to something that suits you
        var predefinedCenter = new OpenLayers.LonLat(1234.5678, 8765.4321);
        geoExtMap.map.setCenter(predefinedCenter);

    }
    else{
        //we found the X and Y parametres in the URL
        var xPar = getParams[inX].split("=");
        var yPar = getParams[inY].split("=");//get the values

            //Check if the values are correct
            if (isNumeric(xPar[1]) && isNumeric(yPar[1])){
                //now that Im sure the values are correct,
                //I can create new center that I will zoom to
                var newCenter = new OpenLayers.LonLat(parseFloat(xPar[1]), parseFloat(yPar[1]));

                //set the location on map
                geoExtMap.map.setCenter(newCenter);

                //zoom to location
                geoExtMap.map.zoomToScale(500);
            }       
    }
```

What this hack does is that it takes your usual URL:
http://localhost:1234/qgiswebclient.html?map=pathtomap.qgs
and gives it an "upgrade" that you can use the url in this way:
http://localhost:1234/qgiswebclient.html?map=pathtomap.qgs?X=123456?Y=654321

But in this case it will zoom to those coordinates. You can read the coordinates from the client in the bottom right corner.

Comment: Yeah, please show me this "hack".

Comment: That's a brilliant cheat :D. I tried in another way by using standard epsg:3857 and saving coordinates in qgis application, it opened map in the right place, but I could not use epsg what I wanted. So this code fixed it very well.

Comment: Well I use a different EPSG also and I had problems with the client because the background maps provided in the client couldn't be projected with the EPSG. I disabled the background maps and then it began to work, but I had to provide my own background maps then :).